# How to debug without the red squiggly lines in case of differences between runtime environments (in my case CHROME vs. VS Code)

Tags: javascript, debugging

This is an error that I get in my Chrome console.

```
MetaDocumentQueueWebPart.tsx:575 Uncaught TypeError: this._getFilePreviewLink is not a function
    at MetaDocumentQueueWebPart.onSelectionChanged (MetaDocumentQueueWebPart.tsx:575:12)
    at PaginatingDetailsList.<anonymous> (index.tsx:90:22)
    at window.spModuleLoader.e.notifyAll (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:32505)
    at o.close (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:30964)
    at o.closeAll (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:35972)
    at o.perform (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:35467)
    at o.perform (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:31291)
    at Object.k [as flushBatchedUpdates] (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:31460)
    at r.closeAll (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:35972)
    at r.perform (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:35467)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:430:68043)
    at Object.i [as batchedUpdates] (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:416:29727)
    at dispatchEvent (sp-classic-page-assembly.js?uniqueId=CrW9l:430:69381)
```

For two two reasons it is difficult to debug this error for me.

1. I have not written the code base so it is diffucult for me to understand it.
2. I do not see the error in my VS Code. The error message says the problem is on line 575:12, in the MetaDocumentQueueWebPart.tsx file. But I do not see any red squiggle lines in my VS Code.

[image]

But I do see the error in my google Chrome.

[image]

This is where the function is defined on line 205. I really do not understand why the console is telling me that `this._getFilePreviewLink is not a function`.

[image]

Obviously, this is a junior question. The problem here is that there is a difference in runtime environment (VS Code vs. Chrome) and, therefore I do not see the error in VS Code. But I am so used debugging in VS ode. The red squiggle lines are usually very helpful. But I can not use them here for debugging. What can I do?

Comment: Your browser is running your JS, so that's where you'll see the debugger underline the problematic line, but typically, having just the line number and checking your original code (in VSCode) like you've done is enough. The error suggests that the value of `this` inside of your `onSelectionChange` isn't correct, to see if that's the case we'd need to see how you're calling that method. However, a quick fix that should work is to change `onSelectionChange` to be defined as `private onSelectionChange = (items, selectedItems) => {` so that `this` refers to the class instance.

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks. That worked. This was a good reminder about the nature of the "this" keyword.